# Create a basic movement in unity with c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

can i get a simple code that moves my character (left,right and jump) using c# in Unity, because using transform.translate wont be affected by colliders .
thx ^^

Comment: Look at the Unity3D tutorials: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials, they should be helpful

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Colliders to be considered, you must move the object using its RigidBody component.

```
yourObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(yourVector);
```

Rigidbody will make sure all collisions are recognized and handled.

Answer (score 0):

you can use condition in it and change its parameter into vector3.back or right etc. Like shown below

```
Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward) * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just right click on inspector and Import package > character / cross platform input